# Dynamic button ng-click pass variable to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to pass a variable to a function by using the directive `ng-click`, here is my code:

```
   var name = "John Doe";
   var $element = $('<button ng-click="open(name)" + "Name:" + '</button>').appendTo('#user-list');

   $compile($element)($scope);

   $scope.open = function(name) {
    alert(name); //Will display 'undefined'
   }
```

The append works fine and when I'm inserting `open(123)`, I can see an Alert of **'123'**. But a simple variable like `var name` will be `undefined`. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why on Earth do people create a button with jQuery, append it to the DOM with jQuery, then use Angular to click it?? Just use Angular already!

Comment: @JeremyThille Good point, then show us an example of implementing this with a full AngularJS solution?

Comment: Write your button in the view and display it / hide it on condition : in your HTML file, write something like `<button ng-click="open(name)" ng-show="someCondition">{{name}}</button>`. When you click the button, it will launch `$scope.open( $scope.name )`. Creating a button and appending it to the DOM is the jQuery way. If you want to develop with Angular, just FORGET JQUERY and do it the Angular way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use like `ng-click="open(name)"` then `name` should be like angular `scope variable`. but there's no scope variable called `name` but you have a variable called `name` That's why you getting `undefined` alert,and it's not within scope (not a scope variable).

And if you need to alert `"John Doe";` which is `var name = "John Doe";` then you have to modify it like scope variable as below,

```
$scope.name = "John Doe";

var $element = $('<button ng-click="open(name)">Name:</button>').appendTo('#ex1');

$compile($element)($scope);

$scope.open = function(name) {
    alert(name); //Will display 'undefined'
}
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JubQ1fSTIATmukhVbvBK?p=preview)

Comment: i still get undefined, can you please provide an exemple? I need to display John Doe on the open() function.

Comment: Hi I updated with an example, probably the created button is incorrect.

Comment: I have this same solution.

Comment: @K.Toress Thanks it does make sense now and it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra single quote.  Try this:

```
var $element = $('<button ng-click="open(name)" + "Name:" + </button>').appendTo('#user-list');
```

Comment: there are two issues here, first the <button> tab missing close ">", and second the name should be in scope by $scope.name="Joe Doe"